# Error de unicidad al agregar datos en un tabla

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla en PostgreSQL 13 con la siguiente escructura:

```
CREATE TABLE rasgos_mge (
    id SERIAL primary key,
    seccion INTEGER,
    localidad INTEGER,
    manzana INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT rasgo_unico UNIQUE (seccion, localidad, manzana)
);
```

nótese la restricción `rasgo_unico` formada por los campos `seccion`, `localidad` y `manzana`.

Ahora quiero agregar datos de otra tabla, con esta consulta:

```
INSERT INTO rasgos_mge
SELECT l.seccion, l.localidad, 9999 as manzana from localidad l;
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
[2021-03-23 12:00:44] [23505] ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «rasgos_mge_pkey»
[2021-03-23 12:00:44] Detail: Ya existe la llave (id)=(4).
```

Sin embargo, cuando consulto los valores de `id` no tengo el id=4:

```
comunidades=# SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM rasgos_mge;
  min  |  max
-------+-------
 23449 | 46896
(1 fila)
```

y al consultar el siguiente valor de la secuencia obtengo:

```
comunidades=# SELECT nextval('rasgos_mge_id_seq');
 nextval
---------
   46901
(1 fila)
```

¿Cómo puedo agregar los datos de la tabla localidad a la tabla rasgos_mge?

Comment: lo más probable no es que el error sea la llave `id=4` sino que estás entregando algún valor duplicado de sección y localidad

Comment: No sé que tanto difiera postgresql del estándar, pero para mi que a la sentencia `insert` le falta la lista de campos. De otra forma, va a tomar el primer campo como `id`. Debiera ser `insert into rasgos_mge (seccion, localidad, manzana)...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que al no especificar los nombres de las columnas en la sentencia INSERT, hace la correspondecia por el orden de los campos (el primero con el primero, etc.). En este caso lo que está haciendo es insertar los valores del SELECT de la siguiente manera: la seccion (de la tabla localidad) la inserta en la columna id (de la tabla rasgos_mge), la localidad en la columna seccion, y la constante 9999 en la columna localidad, quedando vacía la columan manzana (de la tabla rasgos_mge).

Ahora bien, en el SELECT (sobre la tabla localidad) hay mas de una fila con valor 4 en la columna seccion, Postgresql inserta todas las filas resultantes del SELECT (en la tabla rasgos_mge), pero cuando se termina de ejecutar la sentencia realiza el chequeo de las restricciones (constraints), al chequear la restricción de llave primaria encuentra que hay filas duplicadas con id con valor 4 (habrá filas duplicadas con otros valores de id seguramente, pero es el primero que encuentra), por eso muestra el error: "ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «rasgos_mge_pkey» Detail: Ya existe la llave (id)=(4).".

Como bien muestran tus queries, antes del intento de INSERT no había filas con id = 4 en la tabla rasgos_mge, y el valor de la sequencia es correcto (es superior al máximo id de la tabla rasgos_mge).

La sentencia correcta debería ser:

```
INSERT INTO rasgos_mge (seccion, localidad, manzana)

SELECT l.seccion, l.localidad, 9999 AS manzana 
  FROM localidad l;
```